# mongoose populate two simple schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am stuck with mongoose `populate()` method.

Here is my schemas:

```
const GroupSchema = Schema({
  title: String,
  ips: [
    {
    ip: String,
    hostname: String,
    added : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('groups', GroupSchema);

const UserSchema = Schema({
  username: String,
  ip: String,
  groups: [
    {
     _id : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'groups'},
     added : { type : Date, default: Date.now }
    }
  ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

I am trying to join `users.groups[]._id` with `groups._id` but absolutely no luck.

Here is how I tried:

```
  User.find().
    populate('groups').
    exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);    
      console.log(user);
  });
```

getting this result:

```
 { _id: 5b3e039a2f714d38ccf66cax,
    username: 'rrrr',
    ip: '10.1.1.1',
    groups: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0 } ]
```

I want to get like this:

```
 { _id: 5b3e039a2f714d38ccf66cax,
    username: 'rrrr',
    ip: '10.1.1.1',
    groups: [{ title: sssss, added: ssss }, {title: xxxx, added: ssss}] ],
    __v: 0 } ]
```

Comment: you are getting the data in `groups: [ [Object], [Object] ]`... Try to console with `user[0].groups`  or `user[0].groups[0]`

Comment: not working. I am getting this:
GET /users 304 10.850 ms - -
{ added: 2018-07-07T16:14:41.689Z,
  _id: 5b3de77deea8fa128428421d }

Comment: from your console `{ _id: 5b3e039a2f714d38ccf66cax,
    username: 'rrrr',
    ip: '10.1.1.1',
    groups: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    __v: 0 } ]` it seems that you are getting groups... What is the problem?

Comment: for example user[0] have  two groups but it's not populated:

User.find().
    populate('groups').
    exec(function (err, user) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(user[0].username);
      console.log(user[0].groups[0].hostname);
      console.log(user[0].groups[1].hostname);
  });

I am getting 'undefined'

Comment: try to console `console.log(user[0].groups[0].title)` or `console.log(user[0].groups[0].ips[0].hostname)` you will get the data

Comment: sorry it's really  not working :( I am getting "undefined". I think it's something wrong with Schemas or populate() :/

Comment: if you are not getting data with populate then you can use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) as well

Comment: ok thanks, I will try to find out how to use lookup

Comment: it worked with $lookup , thank you very much

Comment: which version you used for `$lookup` 3.4 or 3.6 ?

Comment: Mongodb version 4.0 :/

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation

If you are using mongodb version **3.4** and below

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$groups" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Groups.collection.name,
    "let": { "groupId": "$groups._id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$groupId" ] } } }
    ],
    "as": "groups._id"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$groups._id" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "username": { "$first": "$username" },
    "ip": { "$first": "$ip" },
    "groups": { "$push": "$groups" }
  }}
])
```

If you are using mongodb version **3.6** and above

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$groups" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Groups.collection.name,
    "localField": "groups._id",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "groups._id"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$groups._id" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "username": { "$first": "$username" },
    "ip": { "$first": "$ip" },
    "groups": { "$push": "$groups" }
  }}
])
```